# How do I configure sendmail for integration testing?

Tags: unix, centos, sendmail

I have a virtual CentOS machine, and I need to configure sendmail for integration testing. I need sendmail to accept all e-mail from anywhere, and not do any user validation. I just need it to accept all incoming valid e-mails and not complain nor reject for any reason. And sendmail should not forward the mail to anywhere else.

All of the setup documentation I have read pertains to making a "working" server as opposed to a "dummy" or "stub" server.

How can I configure this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean `sendmail`? Or do you just mean "email"? Have you tried anything for this? Have you looked at the documentation at all?

Comment: I do indeed mean sendmail and not e-mail. I have looked at the documentation. Everything that I have read is for setting it up to be a "working" server as opposed to a "dummy" server for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sendmail configuration for software testing environment

Choose your mix of the fixes below:

**sendmail.mc** : To redirect all **outgoing** messages to local mailbox `user1`

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`local:user1')dnl
```

**sendmail.mc** : To redirect messages to all addresses in local email domains (normally delivered to local mailboxes) to mailbox of `user1'

```
define(`MAIL_HUB',`local:user1')dnl
```

**access** file : To allow relaying (accepting message to non local email addresses) from specific IP addresses:

```
# relay from 192.168.0.1
connect:192.168.0.1   RELAY
# relay from 192.168.1.0/24
connect:192.168.1   RELAY
# relay from 172.32.0.0/16
connect:172.32  RELAY
```

Releasing more test do not make sense in most testing environments
(e.g. no checks existence of envelope sender domain)

---

1. `sendmail.mc` must be compiled into `sendmail.cf`
2. `access` file must be compiles usually into access.db file

More goodies possible:

- storing ALL envelope recipients in message headers (message to multiple recipients not mentioned in email headers)